# ipv6 link local addresses in /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, configuration, ipv6

I'm trying to ssh to a server on my LAN via ipv6. in order to save time and not to type
`ssh fe80::301b:7acc:bc33:a191%wlp1s0` I tried to define the host in `/etc/hosts`.

The problem is that with link local addresses you need to specify the interface, but when I try to add

`fe80::301b:7acc:bc33:a191%wlp1s0 ubuntu`

and then run `ssh ubuntu`

I get

`$ ssh ubuntu`
`ssh: connect to host ubuntu port 22: Invalid argument`

Neither I cant ping ubuntu, BUt if I do `ping -I wlp1s0 ubuntu` then it works.

So question is how do you specify hosts by link local ipv6 addresses? Maybe I should do something else than editing /etc/hosts?

I'd rather not run DNS server or some other "heavy" solution:) I just need to specify one host at the end.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, so I'll leave an answer here for future poor user like me.

TL;DR

So in order to name resolution work properly one need to activate LLMNR by editing

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and uncommenting the line `LLMNR=yes` and restarting corresponding service by `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` on all hosts that you want the hostname to be resolved.

Longer answer.
as stated in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452527/ipv6-link-local-address-in-etc-hosts?noredirect=1&lq=1
basically because of glibc (and all network using soft will use calls to that lib see  getaddrinfo(3) for example) there is no point to use /etc/hosts file. But instead one should use LLMNR. By default in Ubuntu 20.10 as of this writing LLMNR is not enabled by default, so one should enable it manually. You do it on all hosts names of which you would like to be resolved automatically.

Some reading
man systemd-resolved.service
resolvectl
resolved.conf